# Get array hash values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

So I am trying to grab all high schools and graduate schools from this array of hashes:

```
"education": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "110703012290674", 
        "name": "Kunskapsgymnasiet Malmö"
      }, 
      "year": {
        "id": "136328419721520", 
        "name": "2009"
      }, 
      "type": "High School"
    }, 
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "112812485399398", 
        "name": "Malmö University"
      }, 
      "year": {
        "id": "118118634930920", 
        "name": "2012"
      }, 
      "concentration": [
        {
          "id": "104076956295773", 
          "name": "Computer Science"
        }
      ], 
      "type": "Graduate School", 
      "classes": [
        {
          "id": "165093923542525", 
          "name": "Programmering", 
          "description": "Kursen fokuserar på metoder och tekniker vid utveckling av webbapplikationer med hjälp av HTML5."
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Like this:

```
def add_friends
    facebook.get_connections("me", "friends",   :fields => "name, id, education").each do |hash|
      self.friends.where(:name => hash['name'], :uid => hash['id'], 
                                                :highschool_name => hash['education']['school']['name'] if hash['type'] == "High School",
                                                :graduateschool_name => hash['education']['school']['name'] if hash['type'] == "Graduate School").first_or_create
    end
  end
```

And I tried something like this to:

```
def add_friends
    friends_data = facebook.get_connections("me", "friends",   :fields => "name, id, education")
    friends_data.each do |hash|
      friend.name = hash["name"]
      friend.uid = hash["id"]

      if hash["education"]
        hash["education"].each do |e|
          if e["type"] == "High School"
            friend.highschool_name = e["school"]["name"] if (!hash["education"].blank? && !e["school"].blank?)

          elsif e["type"] == "Graduate School"
            friend.graduateschool_name = e["school"]["name"] if (!hash["education"].blank? && !e["school"].blank?)
          end
        end
      end
      friend.save!
      friend
  end
end
```

But i get this erro: `undefined local variable or method`friend'
I think there is a missing connection to the friend model that are missing..

Comment: It is not a duplicate @SergioTulentsev, I tried to explain it to you and even brought you to a chat to explain it even further..

Comment: The variable friend is never initialized. that has nothing to do with the error. if you delete everything in the method except the last 2 lines, the errror would be the same

Comment: @leifg, you are right. Where should I initialize the friend variable?

Comment: The thing is: you are currently showing code without any contexts. The question of you was how to get certain values out of a hash. But you provide a method calle add_friends then you call something on a facebook object. I cannot really figure out what you are trying to achieve, because your question doesn't match the code. Therefore I cannot tell you where to initialize the variable (and with what value)

Comment: @leifg, check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415757/initialized-friend-model-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Array#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select) There you can just specify conditions to get all values that match certein criteria:

```
schools.select{|school| school["type"] == "High School" || school["type"] == "Graduate School"}
```