# initialized friend model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I building an app where a user sign in throw there facebook account and the I grab their friends and their education history. It goes something like this:

The user signs in and goes to the SessionsController#Create:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
  end
end
```

The SessionsController method create calls the method .from_omniauth in the User model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth) 
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      ...more code... 
      user.save!
      user.add_friends
    end
end
```

The .from_omniauth method calls the method add_friends which is inside the User model:

```
def add_friends
    friends_data =  facebook.get_connections("me", "friends",   :fields => "name, id, education")
    friends_data.each do |hash|
      friend.name = hash["name"]
      friend.uid = hash["id"]

      if hash["education"]
        hash["education"].each do |e|
          if e["type"] == "High School"
            friend.highschool_name = e["school"]["name"] if (!hash["education"].blank? && !e["school"].blank?)

          elsif e["type"] == "Graduate School"
            friend.graduateschool_name = e["school"]["name"] if (!hash["education"].blank? && !e["school"].blank?)
          end
        end
      end
      friend.save!
      friend
    end
  end
```

I get this error:

```
NameError in SessionsController#create
undefined local variable or method `friend' for #<User:0x007fad11d50eb0>
```

And I know this means that I have to initialized variable friend, but I have no idea about how to do that. Any ideas, it would be very helpful! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `friend = Friend.new` in the loop:

```
friends_data.each do |hash|
    friend = Friend.new   # <-----------
    friend.name = hash["name"]
    friend.uid = hash["id"]
```

Comment: One problem, my friend model looks like this: [uid, name, highschool_name, graduateschool_name, user_id, created_at, updated_at] but the user_id is empty. So I have to save in an other way, any ideas? my schema looks like this: https://gist.github.com/3083962

Comment: Depends on the meaning of `user_id`. If that is the current user's id, then use `friend.user_id = self.id`. If not, please specify the meaning of the field.

Comment: yes it is the current users_id, if I use friend.user_id = self.id, can I den call the user friends like this: "user.friends" ?

Comment: If you defined the relationship in your models, then yes. Like this: `has_many :friends` in your User model.

Answer (score 0):

First you need Friend model:

```
rails g model Friend user_id:integer uid:string name:string highschool_name:string graduateschool_name:string
rake db:migrate
```

In friend class put belongs_to:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

In user class put has_many:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :friends
end
```

Now your `add_friend`  method should looks like this:

```
def add_friends
    friends_data =  facebook.get_connections("me", "friends",   :fields => "name, id, education")
    friends_data.map do |hash|
      friend=Friend.new
      friend.name = hash["name"]
      friend.uid = hash["id"]
      friend.user_id = self.id

      if hash["education"]
        hash["education"].each do |e|
          next if e["school"].blank?
          if e["type"] == "High School"
            friend.highschool_name = e["school"]["name"]
          elsif e["type"] == "Graduate School"
            friend.graduateschool_name = e["school"]["name"]
          end
        end
      end
      friend.save!
      friend
    end
  end
```

Comment: I have a friend model just like that but with out the :foreign_key=>:uid attribute, why do you use that doesent active record take care of that automatically?

Comment: Rails by default guess `foreign_key` to be the name of the association with an “_id”, so in your model it will be `user_id` not `uid`. Take a look at: [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: you are right,  but my schema looks like this: https://gist.github.com/3083962 and I have notice there nothing happing in the index.

Comment: you're right. if so you must associate friend with user model. I've changed my answer.